# youtube iframe player, video appears cropped in android

Tags: javascript, android, youtube-api

I am trying to play YouTube Videos on android devices using webview  and youtube iframe api. All is well when tested on 4.4, 5.0, and 5.1. But testing the same on 4.3 the video seems to be cropped. ie the video occupies only some 70% of the webview area. As solutions  ?!?!

My code is as follows..

JAVA CODE

```
wvVideo = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvVideo);
wvVideo.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
WebSettings webSettings = wvVideo.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
wvVideo.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
wvVideo.loadUrl("http://test.com/iframeYouTube.html?videoid="+videoURL);
wvVideo.loadUrl("javascript:playVideo();");
```

XML

```
<WebView
android:id="@+id/wvVideo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
android:background="#212121"></WebView>
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%;margin:0;padding:0;width:100%">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
  <body style="background:#212121;height:100%;margin:0;padding:0">

<!-- 1. The <iframe> (and video player) will replace this <div> tag. -->
<div id="player" style="margin:0;padding:0"></div>

<script>

    var Query = function () {

    var query_string = {};
    var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var vars = query.split("&");
    for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
    var pair = vars[i].split("=");

    if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "undefined") {
      query_string[pair[0]] = pair[1];

    } else if (typeof query_string[pair[0]] === "string") {
      var arr = [ query_string[pair[0]], pair[1] ];
      query_string[pair[0]] = arr;

    } else {
      query_string[pair[0]].push(pair[1]);
    }
    } 

    return query_string;
    } ();

    var tag = document.createElement('script');

    tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
    var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

    var player;
    function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
    height:'100%',width:'100%',

    videoId: Query.videoid,
    playerVars: { 'autoplay': 0, 'controls': 0, 'showinfo':0, 'modestbranding':1},
    events: {

    'onReady': onPlayerReady,
    'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange

    }
    });


  }

  function onPlayerReady(event) {
  cueCheck();
  timerFunction();
  videoLength();
  }

  var done = false;

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    Android.playState(event.data+"");

    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      done = true;
    }
  }

  function cueCheck()
  {
    Android.playState("cued");
  }

  function timerFunction(){
  console.log("function");
  Android.updateTimer(player.getCurrentTime()+"");
  setTimeout(timerFunction, 20);
 }

 function videoLength(){
  Android.getVideoLength(player.getDuration()+"");
 }

  function seekTo(val) {
  player.seekTo(val);
  // player.playVideo();
  }

  function pauseVideo(){
  player.pauseVideo()
  }

  function playVideo(){
  player.playVideo()
  }



    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution?